# Undefined reference to ... Using gtk graphics

Tags: c, eclipse, gtk3

I am trying to implementing graphics on a c-program I have recently made. My teacher suggested this link:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.22/c39.html

And I have installed the gtk-package and in Eclipse - I have included the relevant paths and at first glimpse everthing seems fine before compiling.

```
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>


 int main( int argc,char *argv[] )
{
   GtkWidget *window;

   gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

   window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   gtk_widget_show  (window);

   gtk_main ();

   return 0;
}
```

This small example macro from the tutorial is supposed to show a window of 200x200 px.
But when compiling I get the following errors:

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\Ägaren\workspace\cGraphics1\Debug/../src/cGraphics1.c:19:  undefined reference to `gtk_init_abi_check'
 C:\Documents and Settings\Ägaren\workspace\cGraphics1\Debug/../src/cGraphics1.c:21: undefined reference to `gtk_window_new'
 C:\Documents and Settings\Ägaren\workspace\cGraphics1\Debug/../src/cGraphics1.c:22: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
 C:\Documents and Settings\Ägaren\workspace\cGraphics1\Debug/../src/cGraphics1.c:24: undefined reference to `gtk_main'
```

So the question is why I get these errors? Could the answer be that I should user more includes of header-files? I have only one include as you can see. Or could it be so that I need to link several object-files when compiling? In eclipse the compiling argument list look like this:

```
 gcc -o cGraphics1.exe "src\\cGraphics1.o"
```

Comment: Your problem is not with the header file since the .o file compiled successfully.
Your current problem is with the actual definition of the gtk functions which the linker needs to access to build an executable. Basically you are missing -l to the gtk library

Take a look at this tutorial on how to link 'https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html#SEC-HELLOWORLD'

Answer (score 6):

The problem is because the linker can't find the gtk dependencies to compile an executable.

Take a look at this https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/gtk-compiling.html simple guide for help.

Basically you are encourage to use pkg-config to include all the required libraries: `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
I am not sure how to get eclipse to add this to every command (this is roughly the list of libraries: -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0)

Answer (score 2):

linker failed to load required libraries. Add `gtk include path` and `gtk library` to eclipse.

[step to compile gtk in windows using eclipse](http://skt-techblog.blogspot.in/2007/12/build-gtk-program-on-windows-using.html)